# Django - Foreign Keys and the Admin Page

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display the foreign key relations on the admin change page (i.e. the `www.some.url/admin/<app>/<model>/<id>/change/` page):

I have two models linked together via a foreign key relationship like so:

```
# models.py

class Bank(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Branch(models.Model):
    bank = models.ForeignKey('Bank', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='branches')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And I have a model-admin like so:

```
# admin.py

class BankAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('id', 'name',)
```

How can I add the list of branches associated to a given bank on the django-admin-change page? Can I add something to my BankAdmin class that will achieve this?

i.e. If I were to visit the admin page and click on a bank instance (i.e. `www.some.url/admin/<app>/bank/2/change/`) I would like to see the name of the bank and all of its foreign-key related branches.

I've been scouring stackoverflow but have found a solution - please point me in the correct direction if one does exist.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to register a link in BankAdmin's list display that points to a custom admin view showing that Bank's Branches. You could do so like this:

```
# admin.py

class BankAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def link_branches(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            "<a href='/admin/<app>/bank/branches/?id={ bank_id }'> Branches </a>",
            bank_id=obj.id
        )

    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'link_branches')
    admin.site.register(Bank, BankAdmin)
```

Then you just have to create your custom view and update your urls.py to point `/admin/<app>/bank/branches` to that view.

Comment: Thanks - but this only updates the admin-list page not the admin change page. Not sure if I made that clear in the question.

Comment: Ahh I read over that, sorry. I understand now. I think you're looking to modify the form that Django uses on the add/change page for the ModelAdmin. You can create a new form or modify the default one. So I guess you need to modify the existing one and add a field in which displays the linked Branches. [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form)